# Editing to update outdated solution on question about Xdebug on Mac

Tags: support, suggested-edits, specific-answer, outdated-answer

The solution on [Building/Installing Xdebug on Mac OS X with MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379903/building-installing-xdebug-on-mac-osx-with-mamp/) is outdated, and would I love to combine my answer reflecting current affairs into the accepted answer.

Yet it apparently is held up in the edit queue. How can I release it from this lock to update the answer, which might help quite a few users (and avoid confusing them with outdated information)?

Comment: If the answer is outdated, why not post your own? I'm not sure what you're asking here, in truth. I don't see any pending edits on any of those answers, and asking people to get your edit approved on meta is what it's for.

Comment: @Larnu they *did* post their own answer.  I think the reference to the edit queue is noting that it's currently full.

Comment: By the way, you've already done the right thing by posting your own answer.  If you use the new Trending sort, yours is at the top.

Comment: Note that [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) doesn't mean that it's the most correct/updated/best/etc. It just means that the asker found that answer helped the most personally at that time.

Comment: Don't edit accepted answers.  That'll get rejected for trying to change the meaning of the original post.  Answering it yourself is the only correct option here.

Comment: If they do have their own answer they can edit their answer anyway, as it won't go into the queue, so I'm not sure what the problem they are facing therefore is, @RyanM . Unless it's to edit an existing answer to point to theirs, which isn't ok.

Comment: Can I get comments from the down voters, please? It would help improve the quality of SO to get some reasable pointers why. All other comments and answers are helpful to me and probably to others,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link points to a question with 5 answers. The green tick mark on one of them means *this answer was accepted by the OP*.  This mark can only be changed by the OP.

If this answer is obsolete, post a new answer, as you already did. You might add a comment in the accepted answer briefly explaning why it's obsolete. (You already added a comment.) You might include a link to your answer.